# Using querySelectorAll inside a for-in-loop

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm feeling a little stupid to ask this because it should be so simple, but I'm getting pretty frustrated.

I have a few divs that I want to show only one at a time, so I want to hide the rest. My approach:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for (i in elements) {
    elements[i].style.setProperty("display", "none");
}
```

Firefox always says `elements[i].style.setProperty();` is undefined.
I've made a workaround using a normal for-loop without using `in`, but I'd still like to know why this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
elements[i].style.setProperty("display", "none");
```

with

```
elements[i].style.display = "none";
```

As the `HTMLElement.style` property returns a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object that represents the element's inline styles as properties, i.e. `style.property = 'value'`

And use a regular for loop when iterating over array-like objects that has a length, like nodeLists

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("div");

for ( var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Huh. Actually, that's what I did as workaround. I thought it would be more proper code to use a method to set `style`, than setting it via direct property-modification.

And why do I have to use a regular for-loop, exactly? I see that it works, but not why the my version won't...

Comment: Firstly, using a `for..in` loop iterates over all enumerable properties, which can cause issues in some rare cases. Also, there's no guaranteed order in a `for...in` loop, and often times you'd want to iterate over elements in order, especially if modifying those elements, so it's good practice to use a regular `for` loop for nodelists, and that's why they have a length, to be "array-like".